# SJF Scheduling: Selecting Process based on predicted CPU Burst Time

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

In SJF Algorithm, we predict the next CPU Burst time using the formula:
 τ(n+1) = α*t(n) + (1-α)*τ(n). And then we select the process with the shortest predicted burst time. 
Now my question is: do we already have an idea about the CPU burst times of the processes arriving? 
If yes, then why predict the CPU burst time? We could rather just use the shortest time process for scheduling. 
If no i.e., we do not have any idea about the burst times of the processes, how is the predicted burst time τ(n+1) helping us to pick a process?
Hope I am able to explain my confusion.
Thanks.

Comment: I think process BT is not known, cannot be known but we can always predict the aprrox BT based on size,priority,type (i.e. IO or CPU bound) and select the corresponding process given the predicted BT.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question itself. The later condition is true we don't have an idea about burst time of incoming processes this is the reason that we are predicting their burst time τ(n+1). Our prediction may not be 100% right all the time but it'll server the purpose of SJF to a very great extent !
I hope you would've coded this and saw the results if not then i recommend to do so, it'll help a lot understanding this.
This is the application I developed, for my teacher, on some scheduling techniques.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeRyU.png)

Comment: Okay. But suppose we have P2,P3,P4 as our next few processes waiting to be processed. Now we predict a cpu-next burst time. how are we going to select out of these 3 processes based on the predicted burst time? Because the predicted burst time only takes into consideration the previous actual burst time and previous predicted burst time.

Comment: See there are several other methods to predict the burst time, what you are considering is a **Dynamic Method** known as **Exponential average (Aging)**. where **α = smoothing factor** and 0 <= α <= 1, **α It controls the relative weight of recent and past history in our prediction**  _this is the main player here_ you might not taking this into account but this formula gives far more better result than others.

Comment: τ(n+1) = α*t(n) + (1-α)*τ(n).  this equation is the recursive equation. So if you do the back substitution you will realize that each T(n+1) is directly dependent of T(n,n-1,n-2.....1). I hope this answer your question.